# Rails 4, Selenium execute javascript with event

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, rspec

How do I execute my javascript function **addRows()** in this rspec test? The function doesn't run in the test.

my rspec test

```
context 'pressing alt+m, ' do
  it 'appends hello to the dom', :js => true do
    visit welcome_path

    page.execute_script("return addRows(keypressdown = 17, keypressdown = 77);")

    expect(page).to have_content("hello")
  end
end
```

keypressListener.js file

```
function addRows(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if(event.keyCode == 17 && event.keyCode == 77) {
    document.body.append("hello");
  }
}
```

Running the rails server and manually pressing alt+m on this page runs the addRows() function but the test doesn't run the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to execute any Javascript.  Capybara has a `element.send_keys` method.  So something like this might work:

```
page.find('body').send_keys [:alt, 'm']
```

See the [Method: Capybara::Node::Element#send_keys](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Asend_keys) for details.

Comment: Per your suggestion, as "A Element represents a single element on the page" I used variable = page.find 'body' and then called variable.send_keys [:alt, 'm'] to make the test pass. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Excellent!  I added the info from your experience to my answer.